# Make part of an image transparent

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to put an image on a button, but I want part of the image to be transparent.  How do I do this?

Comment: Could you edit the image and save it as a PNG with transparency? Seems like the easiest option unless you can't do it for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [`Image.OpacityMask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743320.aspx) property. You can give it a brush that specifies the region you want to be transparent.

**EDIT**: From [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9a3d52b9-7c3f-47f6-943c-d394561d917f):

> There is no direct support for
>   color-keying a bitmap in WPF. 
>   However, it is fairly easy to
>   implement on your own.  Dwayne has
>   implemented a ColorKeyBitmap on his
>   blog:
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/dwayneneed/archive/2008/06/20/implementing-a-custom-bitmapsource.aspx
>   I believe it links to the code on
>   Codeplex as well.  You could also
>   accomplish this simply by reading your
>   bitmap into system memory, iterating
>   through all the pixels and setting
>   their values yourself, and
>   constructing a new bitmap out of that
>   array.

Comment: Can you make the opacity mask target a color instead of a region?

Comment: I've seen images that have purple backgrounds.  There's a way to force that color to become transparent.  Is there a way to do this in WPF?

Comment: Dwayne's project does not build, so I cannot use it.  I'm puzzled here.  Putting an image on a button is a standard practice.  Are you saying there's no easy way to do this in WPF?

Comment: No it's incredibly easy to put an Image on a Button. As simple as this:

<Button>
 <Image/>
</Button>

What is not easy is setting a transparent color key. You might want to try the approach of reading the bitmap into memory and setting the pixel values yourself.

Comment: the link is broken, does anybody have a working link?

Answer (score 3):

Use a paint program (I use Paint.Net) to change the area you want transparent to an alha=0 color. Then save the image (mine was JPG) as a PNG. Seemed to work fine for me in the WPF Image control.