# Making bitmaps with magenta background appear transparent in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, color-key

I'm in process of converting some legacy software that is 15 years old into WPF and its graphics are often some 8-bit bitmaps with magenta background, something like this:

[image: Transparency test]

With Gdi32 it was common approach to use magenta as transparency key to draw graphics. With `System.Drawing` it would be a one liner, i.e. `_myImg.MakeTransparent(Color.Magenta)`. But what about WPF? Is there even such a thing as *standard practice* for aforementioned scenario?

I was really hoping this would work out of the box:

```xml
    <Image Width="128">
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="Media\opacityTest.bmp" />
        </Image.Source>
        <Image.OpacityMask>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Magenta" />
        </Image.OpacityMask>
    </Image>
```

Alas, although it is allowed, it does nothing:

[image: The result]

Am I missing something or is this impossible in WPF?

Ultimately, I may have to write code to convert these bitmaps into transparent pngs, cache them somewhere and load those instead. If so, does anyone know of any resources that can help me accomplish this aside from Gdi+?

There is a similar question: [Make part of an image transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677120/make-part-of-an-image-transparent). But no definitive answer (or I really can't quite believe it's not possible).

Comment: OpacityMask is something completely different. Take you favorite image editor and replace magenta by a pixel value with zero alpha value.

Comment: @Clemens I would if that were possible - these images are configurable and stored in the database, used by many other apps on many platforms - unfortunately I can't change the images I can only change my app.

Comment: You can of course always load a System.Drawing.Bitmap and convert it to a WPF BitmapSource. You'll find many examples here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating a new image (32bit pargb) based on the original image and a color key, here's the code for whatever it's worth:

```
BitmapSource MakeTransparent(BitmapSource img, Color maskColor)
{           
    var format = PixelFormats.Pbgra32;
    var stride = ((img.PixelWidth * format.BitsPerPixel + 31) & ~31) >> 3;
    var pixels = new byte[img.PixelHeight * stride];

    img.CopyPixels(pixels, stride, 0);

    for (var i = 0; i < stride * img.PixelHeight; i += 4)
        if (Color.FromRgb(pixels[i + 2], pixels[i + 1], pixels[i]) == maskColor)
            for (var j = i; j < i + 4; j++)
                pixels[j] = 0;

    return BitmapSource.Create(
        img.PixelWidth, img.PixelHeight,
        img.DpiX, img.DpiY,
        format,
        null,
        pixels,
        stride);
}
```

It does not use `System.Drawing` so no Gdi+ required, it simply modifies the pixel array replacing the specified `maskColor` with premultiplied alpha rgb values set to 0.

Example usage:
`TestImage = MakeTransparent(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"opacityTest.bmp", UriKind.Relative)), Colors.Magenta);`

The result:

[image]

Comment: @Usman it does but I wouldn't recommend jpg as it is a lossy format and your background may have compression artefacts that will be visible in the output image.